# A decorator-creating class

Tags: python, class, decorator

I am writing a bunch of code that has a possibility of mutable outputs, like an arithmetic function where I could have the output be a float or an int. Basically my problem is that if I were to create a decorator for each object type I need (probably seven or eight), I would go insane with the constant repetition of:

```
def Int(fn):
    def wrapper():
        return int(fn())
    return wrapper
```

What I want to have is a class like below that would create a decorator based on the name it's instantiated with and it would be a copy of the function above but with the appropriate type modifications.

```
class Decorator(object):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
    ...


Int = Decorator()

# Then I can use @Int
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: did you considered the option of passing args to `def wrapper()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have `Decorator` know what name it will be assigned to.  Assignment occurs *after* instantiation, so the object will have already been created by the time it is assigned a name.

You could however make a decorator that creates decorators dynamically:

```
from functools import wraps
def set_return_type(typeobj):
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return typeobj(func(*args, **kwargs))
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

You would then use this decorator by giving a type object argument for the type you want:

```
@set_return_type(int)   # Causes decorated function to return ints
@set_return_type(float) # Causes decorated function to return floats
```

Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> from functools import wraps
>>> def set_return_type(typeobj):
...     def decorator(func):
...         @wraps(func)
...         def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
...             return typeobj(func(*args, **kwargs))
...         return wrapper
...     return decorator
...
>>> @set_return_type(float)
... def test():
...     return 1
...
>>> test()
1.0
>>>
```

Comment: thanks, sorry of the late response. I will be using this idea in my build.